# How to create a stacked barchart where each bar is a different variable? In R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am trying to create a barplot with 5 bars, *each bar representing a different variable*. Each variable is a factor with the same number of categorical levels (4). I wish to have them stacked so that the "fill" is the level (i.e. 1, 2, 3, or 4). Each bar should total 100%, and each stacking level within a bar should represent a proportion that 100%.

This is my first attempt at a reprex so hopefully it works.

```
df <- structure(list(icap_1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
    icap_2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), icap_3 = structure(c(3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", 
    "3", "4"), class = "factor"), icap_4 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
    "4"), class = "factor"), icap_5 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Essentially this is just to visualize the distribution of each variable. I have seen examples from other programs but cannot seem to find an example online. Any tips are hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I hope that I'm understanding your question correctly.
You can `gather` the variables together to make them easily interpretable by `ggplot`.

```
df %>% gather() %>% ggplot(aes(key, value)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

EDIT in response to comment:

```
df %>% gather() %>% ggplot(aes(key, fill = value)) + geom_bar()
```

Will give you[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but the levels (1-4) are actually categorical in nature (I've edited my original post to be more clear and updated the sample df have factored levels)

Comment: Aha! I (think I) understand - check out my edited answer.  If you have different total numbers within each variable (icap_1, for example) then you'll need to change the identity within `geom_bar`.

Comment: Worked for me - thank you! Now to turn the counts to proportions/%s  once in the long/gathered form...